# How to click element under <a href> link using Selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPdIx.png)

using Selenium + Java. I need to click the filter button.

Currently, I am using below code but it doen't work.

```
WebElement filter = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Filter"));
filter.click();
```

Xpath - //*@id="frmBookingListing"]/div[3]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPdIx.png)/div[3]/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPdIx.png)/div/div[2]/a[2]

cssSelector - .searchFilter

I don't know what's wrong with my code. please help to click on filter button.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Avoid `By.linkText()` for low reliability. If there are more elements with the text, you get the first one instead of the desired one. Please share your full code sample including output and page url if not confidential.

Comment: @pburgr - my Html code -> <a href="Javascript:;" class="btn btn-typ4 searchFilter" title="Filter"><span class="fa fa-filter mrg5-R"></span>Filter</a> and my java code is - > WebElement filter = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Filter")); filter.click();

Comment: @pburgr - Output - no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Filter"}

Comment: filter = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Filter']"));

Comment: @Easty77 - Not working as you suggested.

Comment: @Ash can you share URL?

Comment: @pburgr - URL is confidential - Please check Image, xpath, cssSelector, Code in question detail. I hope that is enough. Still I am unable to locate that element, tried with many times but not working. :(

Comment: Regarding the sample dynamic xpath `"//a[@class='btn btn-typ4 searchFilter']"` should work. But without accessing the page and trying by myself I can tell what's wrong.
Try `Thread.sleep(miliseconds)` just to see the page (and it's source code) during runtime.

Comment: @pburgr - Used dynamic path as you suggested above, but still not working., tried all possible cases but no luck. Still working on that to click the 'Filter' button. Let me know if still any other way to click the button. Yes I have used thread.sleep as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Ash Try this: `List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));`. Put a breakpoint after this line and debug your code to see all the `a` tags found by driver. One after another identify the tag in the page (position, text, etc.).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.//a[@class='btn btn-typ4 searchFilter' and @title='Filter']/span
```